# Android 11 - Unable to extract the trust manager on AndroidPlatform, sslSocketFactory is class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl

Tags: android, okhttp, android-11

Android 11 - Unable to extract the trust manager on AndroidPlatform, sslSocketFactory is class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl

> Issue is only with Android 11 devices

Comment: Any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: you need describe your question

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a deprecated method https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/fce60e5a09eac198a0f9c676e486163212662230/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.kt#L761

```
    /**
     * Sets the socket factory used to secure HTTPS connections. If unset, the system default will
     * be used.
     *
     * @deprecated [SSLSocketFactory] does not expose its [X509TrustManager], which is a field that
     *     OkHttp needs to build a clean certificate chain. This method instead must use reflection
     *     to extract the trust manager. Applications should prefer to call
     *     `sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory, X509TrustManager)`, which avoids such reflection.
     */
    @Deprecated(
        message = "Use the sslSocketFactory overload that accepts a X509TrustManager.",
        level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR
    )
    fun sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory) = apply {
      if (sslSocketFactory != this.sslSocketFactoryOrNull) {
        this.routeDatabase = null
      }

      this.sslSocketFactoryOrNull = sslSocketFactory
      this.x509TrustManagerOrNull = Platform.get().trustManager(sslSocketFactory) ?: throw IllegalStateException(
          "Unable to extract the trust manager on ${Platform.get()}, " +
              "sslSocketFactory is ${sslSocketFactory.javaClass}")
      this.certificateChainCleaner = Platform.get().buildCertificateChainCleaner(x509TrustManagerOrNull!!)
    }
```

Applications should prefer to call `sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory, X509TrustManager)`, which avoids such reflection.